# Django - How to Define a Model with 2 Field Types for a JSON Import

Tags: django, json, types, field

I'm trying to import data from a JSON file. One of the keys has a value that is either an integer or the word "false" like this:

```
"mc": 75
```

or

```
"mc": false
```

In my models.py file, I don't know how to define the field for the "mc" database entries, since it has 2 kinds of field types (integers or the word false). Is a generic relation appropriate for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations? Or should I just make it a CharField like this?

```
mc = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

I don't know if it matters, but "mc" is referring to the "mana cost" of an item for a game. So if the item usage doesn't have a mana cost, then the value is "false."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define mc as an integer that can be null:

```
mc = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

That way you will either have an integer with the cost or a null value in your database.